# Swagger java spring maven

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, swagger

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-17T18:25:28.977+03:00 ERROR 32696 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:467) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:256) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:201) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:978) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
at com.api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PatternsRequestCondition.getPatterns()" because "this.condition" is null
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.getPatterns(WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.java:56) ~[springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at springfox.documentation.RequestHandler.sortedPaths(RequestHandler.java:113) ~[springfox-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.lambda$byPatternsCondition$3(Orderings.java:89) ~[springfox-spi-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:473) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1307) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1721) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:392) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.requestHandlers(WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java:81) ~[springfox-spring-webmvc-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.withDefaults(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:107) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.buildContext(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:91) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.bootstrapDocumentationPlugins(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:82) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:100) ~[springfox-spring-web-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:284) ~[spring-context-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
... 13 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1

```
package com.api.configs;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.api.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.2.2
 

com.api
api
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
api
api

<java.version>17</java.version>

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Пробовали ответ из https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72235752/cannot-invoke-org-springframework-web-servlet-mvc-condition-patternsrequestcond ?